# How to join the different value rows into single row for a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a table as shown below:

```
Id    Family    Modal
a1     Jack      A381
a2     Jack      B674
a4    Sutyama    789b
a5    Sutyama    987y
```

I wish to get the below output

```
Id    Family    Modal   Overall
a1     Jack      A381   A381,B674
a2     Jack      B674   A381,B674
a4    Sutyama    789b   789b,987y
a5    Sutyama    987y   789b,987y
```

I have try on below code but it return me empty column for the Overall

```
df["Overall"]=df.groupby("Family")["Modal"].apply(' '.join)
```

Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are my rules of thumb when applying functions with `groupby`:

- To compute and return an aggregated output, use `GroupBy.agg` or `GroupBy.apply`, or
- To broadcast an aggregated result back to the original rows, use `GroupBy.transform`.

This is a use case for the second rule:

```
df['Overall'] = df.groupby("Family")["Modal"].transform(','.join)
df

   Id   Family Modal    Overall
0  a1  Jack     A381  A381,B674
1  a2  Jack     B674  A381,B674
2  a4  Sutyama  789b  789b,987y
3  a5  Sutyama  987y  789b,987y
```

Comment: Let say there is duplicate for the modal column and i wish to remove first before join, so i try this df.groupby("Family")["Modal"].transform(','.join(pd.unique(df.Modal))) but notice not able work, any ideas on this?

Comment: @ShiJieTio Need a `lambda` here with `set`: `df.groupby("Family")["Modal"].transform(lambda x: ','.join(set(x)))`

Comment: @ShiJieTio and `df.groupby("Family")["Modal"].transform(lambda x :','.join(x.unique())) `

Answer (score 2):

You can also fix your code by `map`

```
df["Overall"]=df.Family.map(df.drop_duplicates(['Family','Modal']).groupby("Family")["Modal"].apply(' '.join))
df
Out[45]: 
   Id   Family Modal    Overall
0  a1     Jack  A381  A381 B674
1  a2     Jack  B674  A381 B674
2  a4  Sutyama  789b  789b 987y
3  a5  Sutyama  987y  789b 987y
```